# Create Android App Support for tablets

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I want to create app for support different sizes of tablets, I added this for my Manifest

```
 <supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But my app design does not fit for different device screens, I used Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: Read the training topic [Designing for Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) and the guide topic [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have several dimen.xml files in values folders such as values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-sw800dp. Next, update values in dimen.xml files(increase or reduce values of dimen items)